# Query to display results next to each day of month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a calendar table setup, I have left joined another table based on matching days but wish to display the rest of the full month even if no matches, I am trying to build a graph of current month showing each day's progress.

My query is:

```
SELECT calTable.db_date, COUNT(DISTINCT tbl_data.id) as resultsCounts
FROM calendarTable as calTable
LEFT JOIN tbl_data as tbdata ON DATE(tbl_data.startDate) = DATE(calTable.db_date) 
WHERE calTable.db_date between '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30' 
GROUP BY calTable.db_date
```

I realise as soon as I join the other table which has no future dates that this is causing the rest of the dates not to show, what can I do to show the rest of the current month,

```
array (size=3)
'db_date' => string '2019-04-07' (length=10)
'resultsCounts' => string '19' (length=2)

array (size=3)
'db_date' => string '2019-04-08' (length=10)
'resultsCounts' => string '0' (length=2)

array (size=3)
'db_date' => string '2019-04-09' (length=10)
'resultsCounts' => string '0' (length=2)
```

Same goes if I want to show last months data and if there is a day with no results, for it still to be included as 0 etc.

Calendar Table looks like this:

---

```
id | db_date | year | month | day | quarter | week | day_name | month_name 

20190407 | 2019-04-07 | 2019 | 4 | 7 | 2 | 14 | sunday | April
```

Apologies on formatting, not sure how to do do it.

Comment: which is the content of the table  calendarTable  ??? .. have you a valid set of date for covering your selecting range?

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge - I've put an example of the calendar table above - as for a valid set of dates, yes in the calendar table, but not for the table joining as there are no future dates set yet.

Comment: you have just one day? or is full with all the day of your needed  range ?

Comment: No, the calendar table goes all the way to 2030 and increments by day - whereas the other table doesn't, if there's a product sold, it fills out a date / time etc - so some dates might be missing from the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have valida date  in calendarTable for all the date in range could your issue i related to the null result  try adding an ifnull

```
SELECT calTable.db_date, ifnull(COUNT(DISTINCT tbdata.id), 0) as resultsCounts
FROM calendarTable as calTable
LEFT JOIN tbl_data as tbdata ON DATE(tbdata.startDate) = DATE(calTable.db_date) 
WHERE calTable.db_date between str_to_date('2019-04-01', '%Y-%m-%d') 
      AND tr_to_date('2019-04-30' , '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY calTable.db_date
```

Comment: No, unfortunately still not returning anything past today - I guess I could do it another way by getting the month days first in an array, then loop through for each day and count the results that way, I just wondered if there was a better way?

Comment: startdate = timestamp - db_date = date

Comment: the str_to_date thing cleared it up, thanks a million :)